# time format using mktime and strtotime

Tags: php

I am trying to get the time in 24hrs/12 hours format.
I have a timestamp which I got from `mktime` and `strtotime`.

Will I get a proper time format by doing the below changes?

I was told that the values are not the same for the `$timstamp` when did for `mktime` and `strtotime`.

```
if (true) {
        $timstamp = mktime(5 + $hours, 10 + $minutes, 0, 13, 03, 2020);
} else {
         $currentdate ='13-03-2020 05:10:20';
         $timstamp = strtotime($currentdate);
}

$date = date('m/d/Y', $timstamp);

if($timeformat != 'HH24:MI:ss' ){
    $time = date('h:i A', $timstamp);
}else{
    $time = date('H:i', $timstamp);
}
```

Comment: A timestamp is the same no matter how you created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values should be the same - all functions `mktime()`, `strtotime()` and `date()` depend on current timezone setting (see [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)), unless You specify timezone in the string in `strtotime()`. Try for Yourself:

```
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());
string(16) "America/New_York" 

var_dump(date('h:i A', mktime(5, 10, 20, 13, 03, 2020)));
string(8) "05:10 AM" 

var_dump(date('H:i', mktime(5, 10, 20, 13, 03, 2020)));
string(5) "05:10" 

var_dump(date('h:i A', strtotime('13-03-2020 05:10:20')));
string(8) "05:10 AM" 

var_dump(date('H:i', strtotime('13-03-2020 05:10:20')));
string(5) "05:10" 

var_dump(date('H:i', strtotime('13-03-2020 05:10:20 Europe/Prague')));
string(5) "00:10"
```